# How to redirect to another website and send the JWT as bearer token as well using JS

Tags: javascript, redirect, jwt, xmlhttprequest

I need to redirect to another website and send the JWT as a bearer token as well.

Can I use `XMLHttpRequest` like this?

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', redirectUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
      window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
    }
  };
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it?

Comment: Do you write also the code in the target website?

Comment: @TasosK. No, I don't.

Comment: If this is the case, then you can't do much. There is no standard way to set headers for requests on a different domain. In order to achieve that, there must be an implementation on both ends. For example, the source website sends the token (in a query string) but also the target website processes the incoming value from the query string and use it.

Comment: If the `redirectUrl` is meant to be visited by a browser, it cannot rely on the `Authorization: Bearer` header for authentication, because a browser never sends that when navigating to a URL. Please explain how authentication for that site works when I use the site directly (without your program).

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` to redirect the user to another website.

Solution:

To redirect the user to another website with a **JWT** token, you can use `fetch` to get target website and send the **JWT** token with the request,  then redirect the user to the website.

```js
const redirectUrl ="https://example.com"
const token = "ey..."
 
fetch(redirectUrl, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  }
})
.then(() => {
  window.location.href = redirectUrl;
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Your solution is equivalent to the `XMLHttpRequest` approach in the question. Both will work only if the target website implements [tag:cors] and allows the `Authorization` header and credentials in `fetch` requests.